# What is the purpose of including lower density bitmaps?

Tags: android, bitmap, android-resources

In my apps so far I have mostly only included high density bitmaps and declared my ImageView sizes in dp (of course). I've gone through [Supporting Multiple Screens](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html) again and I still do not see much of a point in including lower density bitmaps since the system will just scale them appropriately for lower density devices.

I can't imagine scaling a bitmap down in Photoshop is going to provide much of a better image than the Android system's scaling. It can be time consuming to scale bitmaps in Photoshop, especially if you want to change something later. The extra bitmaps will increase the .apk size to some degree.

I can see there is a possible performance hit when the system must perform the scaling at runtime, is it ever noticeable? Am I missing something else?

Comment: Quote from the official developer site: You do not need to provide alternative resources for every combination of screen size and density. The system provides robust compatibility features that can handle most of the work of rendering your application on any device screen, provided that you've implemented your UI using techniques that allow it to gracefully resize (as described in the Best Practices)

Comment: But - "To ensure your bitmaps look their best, you should include alternative versions at different resolutions for different screen densities." - why not just include the highest density version?

Comment: Quote again (same source): Although the system scales your layout and drawable resources based on the current screen configuration, you may want to make adjustments to the UI on different screen sizes and provide bitmap drawables that are optimized for different densities. This essentially reiterates the information from earlier in this document.

If you need to control exactly how your application will look on various screen configurations, adjust your layouts and bitmap drawables in configuration-specific resource directories.

Comment: So only when you want to master how your app looks on different screens you have to include the additional resources, however if you are fine with Android system doing this task for you, you are better off with resources in HDPI.

Comment: I can understanding wanting to change the UI based on screen size, but what is the difference between you scaling it down in Photoshop and the Android system doing it?

Comment: I have heard that: Photoshop has better scaling algorithms than Android and that performance hits are only minor on high end devices and starting from JB. That being said, I would like to see some benchmarks to back up these assertions.

The best thing to do IMO, is to test both techniques with a couple assets form your app on different devices (1 low end and 1 high end) and different Android versions (pre-JB and post-JB), and see how it goes.

Comment: There is no difference, its all about how you want to display your layouts on different sizes and resolutions, also how critical it is for your app if Android scales the bitmaps and processes other tasks as well. This topic is very confusing and it really truly took me a week to understand. But once you get the grip, you never lose it!

Comment: There's A LOT of difference! Android scaling is not as good as manually scaling with a photo editor... especially for what concerns ALIASING. Android does its best at sacling graphics, but it's NOT ENOUGH to get decent results.

Answer (score 0):

still there are so many lower end devices(screen and performance ) in market.
for sake of optimization should included at least mdpi and greater.

Comment: I always include ldpi to xxhdpi, actually

Comment: creating ldpi assets is not really needed anymore. The devices are rare and the platform will just scale down mdpi. Read it: http://developer.android.com/design/style/iconography.html

Comment: I still have some ldpi devices. I want my apps to look PERFECT, not SCALED DOWN.